# Why does my click event not fire using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render (){
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>hedlo</div>
  },
   handleClick : function(e){
     alert('--')
   } 

}
```

Why doesn't the click event fire?

Here is my [code](http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/oxRwYM)

Comment: you have typos, take a look at working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzLqWM

Answer (score 4):

You have syntax errors (remove `,` after render, and as your are using ES2015 class you  can not use `key: value` syntax, instead use `handleClick(e) {}` ), change your code like this

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>hedlo</div>
  }

  handleClick(e) {
     alert('--')
  } 
}
```

[`Example`](http://codepen.io/tarasyuk/pen/ZWNyKK?editors=0010#anon-login)